# Automatic Updates Individual Plugins Not Working

Tags: plugins, customization

I am writing a Wordpress plugin for setting automatic updates for individual plugins.  I am unable to verify that the 'auto_update_plugin' filter is working.  Anything I put into the callback function returns nothing.  As if the function is never called.

The filter:

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', array( $this, 'l7wau_auto_update_specific_plugins' ), 10, 2 );
```

The callback function:

```
/**
     * Update specific plugins. Got this from Wordpress codex.
     */
    function l7wau_auto_update_specific_plugins( $update, $item ) {

        // Array for adding the path to file. Use for 3.8.1 and below.
        $new_plugin_array = array();
        $this->plugin_slug = 'changed'; //Test to see if it is working. Nothing here.

        /**
         * Get the array of names/slugs to set to auto-update
         * Added the folder/file.php because the actual slug is not 
         * the file name.  It is the plugin folder and file with header use for 3.8.1 and below.
         */
        $plugins = $this->l7wau_get_array_plugins_to_update();

        if ( in_array( $item->slug, $plugins ) ) {
            return true; // Always update plugins in this array
        } else {
            return $update; // Else, use the normal API response to decide whether to update or not
        }
    }
```

Comment: Starting a function name with numbers is invalid? Try to start with a character. More read http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: The first letter is an 'l'  for short for 'Layer'.  Is it not a 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the above does work.  It just takes 12 hours for the automatic update cycle to happen.  On thing I did change was the importance number for 10 to 20.

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', array( $this, 'l7wau_auto_update_specific_plugins' ), 20, 2 );
```